# Find the active button

Tags: pagination, cypress

[image: pagination]

I am trying to find a way I can get the value of the active button. In my test I need to find out what page is currently selected (active). And then will select another pagination and check that it's the next number.

Comment: what have you tried ? did you try this ? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Find-the-first-li-descendent-within-a-ul

Answer (score 1):

this should select your active button and check if it contains the number 1.

I presumed that the pagination is on your landingpage. Otherwise you have to navigate to the component first.

```
cy.visit('URL')
cy.get('[class="jsx-1699082636 active"]')
.should('contain','1')
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid the react class name. but it seems Cypress uses sizzle's library selector. So modified it to
`cy.get('[class$="active"]')`